# Call Variable length argument method in abstract class when using Mockito spy on subclass throws exception

Tags: java, mockito, variadic-functions

I use Mockito 1.8.0 so I do not have `AnyVararg`. Upgrading to later version of Mockito is not on cards from my team at the moment. So please bear with me.

What the class looks like:

```
public abstract class Parent {

      public void someMethod(String a, String b)
      {
          //.....
      }

      public void foo(String a, String... b)
      {
          //.....
      }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
      public void bar() {
          someMethod(a,b);
          foo(a,b,c);
          methodToFailUsingSpy();
      }
}
```

Unit tests

```
 @Test
 public void someTest() {
       private spyOfChild  = //initialize here;
       doReturn("Something")).when(spyOfChild).methodToFailUsingSpy();
       /*  Tried using this, but did not help.
       doCallRealMethod().when(spyOfChild).foo(anyString());
       */
       spyOfChild.bar();
 }
```

Problem -

When the spy sees `someMethod()`, it calls the real method in the abstract class. But when it sees `foo()`, it tries to find a matching stubbed method i.e control goes to Mockito's `MethodInterceptorFilter`, since it is not able to find a mock, it throws `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

I do not want `foo()` to be mocked. I want the real method to be called like it happens in `someMethod()`. Can someone explain if it is because of using method with variable length arguments with a spy?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Mockito.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mockito/P_xO5yhoXMY/FBeS4Nf4X9AJ

Your example is quite complicated, to reproduce the problem is very simple:

```
class SimpleClass {

    public String varargsMethod(String... in) {
        return null;
    }

    public void testSpyVarargs() {
        SimpleClass sc = Mockito.spy(new SimpleClass());
        sc.varargsMethod("a", "b");
    }
}
```

Even this will produce the error you describe, and the workaround suggested in the link doesn't work for me.

Unfortunately to get around this you will need to upgrade Mockito. Changing to version 1.9.5 makes the above run fine, plus you get the varargs matchers as you say (although note that your problem isn't to do with matchers but how Mockito handles spied varargs methods).

I don't think there were too many huge changes between 1.8.0 and 1.9.5, it shouldn't be too painful.